# Adobe Acrobat Pro DC is not responding to VBA commands

Tags: excel, vba, adobe, acrobat

I am currently writing a macro that takes numbers form an excel index. Then finds the PDF file with the same name and combines them into 1 PDF file.

But I am having trouble getting the part that combines the files to work and I cannot find out why it should not work I have my references set correctly.

This is the part that I am having trouble with.

```
Dim objCAcroPDDocDestination As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim objCAcroPDDocSource As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim i As Integer
Dim iFailed As Integer
Dim strSaveAs As String
Dim MergePDFs As Boolean


strSaveAs = GetNewFolder & "\" & TxtNewFileName.Text
 
On Error GoTo NoAcrobat:
'Initialize the Acrobat objects
Set objCAcroPDDocDestination = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
Set objCAcroPDDocSource = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
 
'Open Destination, all other documents will be added to this and saved with
'a New Filename
objCAcroPDDocDestination.Open (thisarray(LBound(thisarray))) 'open the first file
 
'Open each subsequent PDF that you want to add to the original
  'Open the source document that will be added to the destination
    For i = LBound(thisarray) + 1 To UBound(thisarray)
        
       If objCAcroPDDocDestination.InsertPages(objCAcroPDDocDestination.GetNumPages - 1, objCAcroPDDocSource, 0, objCAcroPDDocSource.GetNumPages, 0) Then
          MergePDFs = True
        Else
          'failed to merge one of the PDFs
          iFailed = iFailed + 1
        End If
        objCAcroPDDocSource.Close
    Next i
objCAcroPDDocDestination.Save 1, strSaveAs 'Save it as a new name
objCAcroPDDocDestination.Close
Set objCAcroPDDocSource = Nothing
Set objCAcroPDDocDestination = Nothing
 
NoAcrobat:
If iFailed <> 0 Then
    MergePDFs = False
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

I hope this is enough information. I don't really want to post the entire code because it is very long.
Thank you for your effort.

Comment: When you try debugging `On Error GoTo NoAcrobat` is inappropriate. Comment it, please and run the code line by line (pressing F8 in VBE) and see what happens. Does the code go into the loop? Put some `Debug.Print' to retrieve `thisarray(LBound(thisarray))` or whatever you suspect going wrong...

Comment: I did this and the code does go into the loop but for some reason it just doesn't open the files even though I have the correct file path. @FaneDuru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, add this line

```
objCAcroPDDocSource.Open (thisarray(i))
```

after

```
For i = LBound(thisarray) + 1 To UBound(thisarray)
```

You did not open the `Source`file and it is nothing to be merged...

Comment: I have added this line and Adobe Acrobat Pro DC is just not responding and it also won't go in to error.

Comment: @Tom: Then, you must check if your `thisarray` array contains more then one element, or their full name is not correct. I copied your code and filled `thisarray` and **it works well after opening the necessary file**. Please, try copying your simplified code as it is, create `thisarray = Array(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "someFile.pdf", ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "someFile2.pdf")` and run the code. I discovered the issue proceeding as I recommended to you to try debugging...

Comment: When I try this method it works but this method has the same output as when I fill the array automatically. However when I do it automatically it doesn't work. I did as you recommended use F8 and a breakpoint before array to see what happens but it doesn't look strange to me. @FaneDuru

Comment: @Tom: This indubitabile proves that your array elements are wrong... The above one is a working code!. You must see, how exactly the files full name look. Try as I recommended: `Debug.Print thisarray(i): Stop`. And see what it returns. No need of `F8`. The code will stop at this line... Try also, `Debug.Print thisarray(LBound(thisarray)):Stop` above the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I have found the issue. It had to do with the file name not the code. The file it was trying to find didn't exist that is why it didn't work.

Comment: @Tom: Your code couldn't work, anyhow, without the code line I inserted. So, does my code answer your question? The code can also be adapted to check if the file exists and finally return a list with file names not existing...

Comment: @Tom: In such a case, we here tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Comment: It works with @FaneDuru addition. However, I cannot find a solution to save the output as the first file in the list, probably very common situation (at least in my case). The routine that did that before I switched to Acrobat DC Pro (old Acrobat X) worked like that. I must admit this is not a big problem as you can mitigate it with a temp file that replaces the first file in the list!